# Is there a way to convert an object key containing an array to an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my current object:

```
{"or_11[and_3][gt@last_closed_sr]":"2019-06-18"}
```

I would like it to look like:

```
{
  "or_11": {
    "and_3": {
      "gt@last_closed_sr": "2019-06-18",
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: Why do you have such an object? I think you should fix it instead, if you can.

Comment: @SMAKSS nothing that even half way worked

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi I might if I can't find a solution, it's part of some old code and I would prefer not to touch it

Comment: I agree with @emrenevayeshirazi, however I've had to do a similar thing before. Here's a fiddle that parses it. https://jsfiddle.net/b5srwdpc/

Comment: @CharlesBamford that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you for understanding that sometimes you just have to work with what you have no matter the conditions.

Comment: @Paige Okay, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer to poorly formatted data is to fix the formatter, not to implement a parser. However, I've worked with systems that encode data like that, so here's a parser.

```js
function parseSquareSeparatedData(data) {
  const result = {};

  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    const keyParts = key.replace(/]/g, "").split("[");
    const last = keyParts.pop();
    let resultPointer = result;
    keyParts.forEach((keyPart) => {
      if (!(keyPart in resultPointer)) {
        resultPointer[keyPart] = {};
      }
      resultPointer = resultPointer[keyPart];
    })
    resultPointer[last] = input[key];
  })

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = '"or_11[and_3][gt@last_closed_sr]":"2019-06-18"';

let first = str.replace(/"/g, '').match(/\w+/)[0];

let pattern = /\[(.+?)\]/g;
let matches = [];
let match;
while(match = pattern.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(match[1])
}

let val = str.replace(/"/g, '').split(':')[1];

let obj = {
  [first]: {
    [matches[0]]: {
      [matches[1]]: val
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```